# check if person is facing camera

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, artificial-intelligence

With [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet) I can get points of the person's nose, shoulders and hips. I am trying to figure out how to check if someone is facing the camera.

There are some easy ideas, but they all run into trouble when I add that the person can come closer or move further away.

**Failed Attempts:**

1. *shoulder distance*: turning makes it smaller, but so does walking away.
2. *Shoulder to Hip Ratio* should work, but it only makes a meaningful change after a large turn. I suppose there might be some noise in the code.

I have an intuition to compare the area of the torso (shoulders and hips) to the height of the torso? Not sure how to quantify it or if there is a better idea?
[image]

Comment: I would use the ratio of shoulder distance (or hip distance) and torso height.

Comment: I will note that I did do that successfully, thanks. It's not perfect because of the range that they can still turn, but it's not so bad so far.